# fitting a button inside a grouped table cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to fit a button to the bounds of a grouped table cell.  As you may know, grouped table views have margins along the left and the right of the cells.  However, the bounds of the cell are as if those margins did not exist.  I COULD hard code the frame but I was curious as to if there was a better way to fit a button inside the cell bounds of a grouped table.

here is my current set up... I also read in another post here to try the autoresizing mask, but that didnt work either.

```
        SubmitButton *search = tableValues.key; //pulling my button object from an array
        search.frame = cell.bounds;
        cell.clipsToBounds=YES;
        [cell addSubview:search];
```

with this, the edges of the button still stretch beyond the margins of the cell.

Thanks

Comment: When creating your frame you could use CGRectMake. Then subtract from cell.bounds.size.width and cell.bounds.size.height. Although, this is really just the same as hard coding I suppose, as you still need some magic number to subtract.

Comment: have you tried to set the button with cell.accessoryView = myButton;? This works if you want to have a button on the right hand side or with customisation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subviews should be added to a cell's contentView, not directly to the cell. The cell's frame is the full width of the table view, even with grouped tables. The cell's contentView is sized properly to take into account plain vs. grouped as well as various cell decorations like delete icon, reorder handles, and disclosure indicators.

Adjust the button's frame to the `contentView` and add the button to the `contentView`.

Comment: I changed my code to be `search.frame = baseCell.contenView.bounds` and `[baseCell.contentView addSubview: search]` for those lines.  The result gave me correct bounds on the left, but the right now extends off screen.

Comment: Make sure you also set the button's `autoresizingMask` for flexible width.

Comment: yeap, that got it.  Thanks rmaddy

Comment: Perfect answer! The first sentence triggered me, as I was adding the subview like [cell addSubview:view] which is wrong. This made the stretching wrong. By changing it to [cell.contentView addSubview:view] it's fixed!